# Call class from other Swift File

Tags: ios, swift, class

I have a piece of code that is being used to go from one ViewController to another ViewController in a different storyboard. Now, since I have a lot of storyboards and ViewControllers, I wanted to create a different file that manages my navigation code. But I have a problem to get my code working from the navigation file in my view controller files. I hope that you can help me with this.

Here is the code for navigation:

```
class Navigation{
    func viewNavigation(){
        var storyboardName:String
        var controllerName:String

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil);
        let controller = 
storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: controllerName) as 
UIViewController; present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

I also have problem with the "present" code right, now so any tip on that would be most helpful.

Here is the code for my view controller:

```
import UIKit

class GeographicalFeeder: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var GoBackButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var ViewTitle: UINavigationItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var AdministratorButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var ComposeButton: UIButton!

    //Navigation Actions
    @IBAction func ToHomeFeederVC(_ sender: Any) {
    }
```

The code needs to be processed in the IBAction where I can fill in the destination storyboard and the destination view controller.

Comment: FYI - it is standard that variable and method names start with lowercase letters. You should fix the names of your outlets.

Comment: Thank you, will do that!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are casting incorrectly.  Your code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil);
        let controller = 
storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: controllerName) as 
UIViewController; present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

You are casting controller as UIViewController when you MUST cast it as the class of the controller you are segueing to.

So replace UIViewController with the ViewController name you created:

```
storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: controllerName) as 
yourViewControllerClassHere
```

Comment: No problem Moritz.  No problem at all.  I'm can honestly say I'm sitting here trying to understand what you were saying.  The code works fine in Playground but will not compile in a ViewController.  Every time I feel like I'm making progress with Swift and XCode, I seem to get set back.. Like yesterday, I should have know that Label. text was an optional as you pointed. out.  No worries.  Have a great day!

Comment: I got it!  I totally get what you are saying now!  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much Moritz!  Honestly, I greatly appreciate it!  I'll be able to ask and answer questions much better going forward.